# Error while Running Python manage.py runserver comman

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows

I have started learning django this was my first tutorial.
First i ran `django-admin startproject` 
This command works according to tutorial but when I run this command 
`python manage.py runserver`
Following Error Occurs but not in tutorial video

```
*Watching for file changes with StatReloader  
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).  
September 27, 2019 - 18:01:04  
Django version 2.2.5, using settings 'first.settings'  
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/  
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.  
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py",
>   line 917, in _bootstrap_inner  self.run()     File
>   "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\threading.py",
>   line 865, in run
>       self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)     File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py",
>   line 54, in wrapper
>       fn(*args, **kwargs)     File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py",
>   line 139, in inner_run
>       ipv6=self.use_ipv6, threading=threading, server_cls=self.server_cls)     File
>   "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
>   line 203, in run
>       httpd = httpd_cls(server_address, WSGIRequestHandler, ipv6=ipv6)      File
>   "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py",
>   line 67, in **init**
>       super().**init**(*args, **kwargs)      File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socketserver.py",
>   line 449, in **init**
>       self.server_bind()   File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py",
>   line 50, in server_bind
>       HTTPServer.server_bind(self)   File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\http\server.py",
>   line 139, in server_bind
>       self.server_name = socket.getfqdn(host)   File "C:\Users\MuBasHer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\socket.py",
>   line 676, in getfqdn
>       hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position
>   6: invalid start byte *

Comment: If you run it like this what happens: python manage.py runserver 127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: What is your hostname? Does it have special characters in it?

Comment: I tried this nothing happend same error

Comment: If you have aliases for your localhost in your host file with characters that are non utf-8 you probably will get this error.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich i just run this command it give me error but not in tutorial 
i simply just created project and then run python manage.py runserver command and it gave me error but not in tutorial

Comment: @MarkBarrett just tell me how to solve i will do it which file i have to edit?

Comment: @MubasherAli: the error is the very last line: `getfqdn hostname, aliases, ipaddrs = gethostbyaddr(name) UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 6: invalid start byte *`. Maybe the problem is that your hostname is not UTF8 and Python expects it to be. So that is why I ask what your hostname is.

Comment: Your hosts file is located here: C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts. If you open that with Notepad and see any special characters in the aliases thats probably the issue. What is listed as the alias for 127.0.0.1 in it?

Comment: @MarkBarrett 
(#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost)
this is the host file contain excluding parenthesis

Comment: If you type hostname into the command prompt and press enter what do you get?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich my hostname. I dont know my hostname

Comment: when i type hostname in concole i get CeaXer® this name

Comment: Okay, as you see the symbol beside the r (looks like an R in a circle), this isn't allowed as a hostname as it is not utf-8. It needs to be changed.

Comment: @MarkBarrett how can i do this

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/change-your-computer-name-in-windows-vista/

Comment: OK let me restart

Comment: If I create answer can you mark it as accepted for the rep?

Comment: i tried but it says your reputation point less than 15 it recorded just

Comment: Yea not upvote but the little tick to accept :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change hostname in Windows to remove any not UTF-8 characters.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, I assume you are using the windows command-line tool as your shell.

If so, then run the command-line tool as `administrator` and
`cd` into your project directory, switch into your working(virtual environment),
then run the `python manage.py runserver` command again.

With these few steps you can startup your development server.
thanks